# bs4 - BeautifulSoup, TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Why am I getting this error? (I know this question has a lot lack of details, but I'm in a hurry and my code is very simple so I would be greatful if someone helped me)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/BABA/alibaba/balance-sheet'

client = ureq(url)
page_html = client.read()
client.close()

page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
balance_sheet = page_soup.findALL("div",{"id":"row10jqxgrid"})
balance_sheet
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-6a2377c6bfca> in <module>
      1 page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
----> 2 balance_sheet = page_soup.findALL("div",{"id":"row10jqxgrid"})
      3 balance_sheet

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `page_soup`?

Comment: Works fine with `page_soup.find_all` but I think this element is dynamically generated with JS. You might edit the question to ask about this and fix the typo.

Answer (score 2):

```
balance_sheet = page_soup.findALL("div",{"id":"row10jqxgrid"})
```

In your code You have written findAll in capital .
write findAll instead of findALL

```
balance_sheet = page_soup.findAll("div",{"id":"row10jqxgrid"})
```

Comment: Okay,thanks i will keep that in mind